# Идентификация цепочки сообщений (FB Messenger)

Tags: php, phpstorm, facebook-api, бот

Доброго времени суток.

При работе с недавно выпущенной платформой от Facebook (для разработки ботов), столкнулся с проблемой, которую не могу решить. Очень надеюсь получить здесь помощь или хотя бы идеи.

Суть проблемы в следующем, есть сервер, которые принимает входящие сообщения, обработчик следующий:

```
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
if (!empty($data['entry'][0]['messaging'])) {
    foreach ($data['entry'][0]['messaging'] as $message) {
        // Skipping delivery messages
        if (!empty($message['delivery'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $senderID = $message['sender']['id'];

        $MessageHelper = new MessageSender($bot,$senderID);

        $command = "";
        // When bot receive message from user
        if (!empty($message['message'])) {
            $command = $message['message']['text'];
            $MessageHelper->replyListener($command);
        } else if (!empty($message['postback'])) {
            $command = $message['postback']['payload'];
            $MessageHelper->postbackListener($command);
            //showCategoriedMenu($bot,$message,$command);
        }
```

Как можно заменить, у нас тут два Listener-а (которые работают не совсем как Listener-ы, а хотелось бы именно это и сделать). 
Код Listener-а следующий:

```
     switch ($command)
    {
        case "Меню":
            $this->showMenu();
            $this->bot->send($this->message);
            break;
        default:
            $this->defaultMessage();
            $this->bot->send($this->message);
            break;
    }

    $this->prevCommand=$command;
```

В строке

```
    $this->prevCommand=$command;
```

Я записываю последнюю команду, которая пришла от пользователя путем POSTBACK. Но при следующем входе в этот Listener эта переменная обнулится, ведь у нас в самом цикле запуска Listener-ов есть объявление класа:

```
    $MessageHelper = new MessageSender($bot,$senderID);
```

Хотелось бы иметь возможность сохранить последнюю команду пользователя, и, исходя из неё делать какие-нибудь выводы.

Comment: Может быть сделать **prevCommand** статической?, или вам нужно обрабатывать именно последнюю команду текущего пользователя? Но тогда всё правильно работает.

Comment: Нужно обрабатывать даже не текущего, а конкретного. В один и тот же момент могут писать несколько пользователей, и я понятия не имею как их можно разделить, чтобы анализировать их сообщения.

Comment: А то, что написано сейчас в коде, не работает почему-то, **prevCommand** постоянно пустое

Comment: Я не знаю как работает FB Messenger, но предположу что методом WebHooks, и дёргает ваш сервер при каком-то событии. Следовательно у вас сессия будет прерываться. И нужно сохранять её результаты по завершению( в базу, кэш или еще куда либо )

Comment: Все верно, мэсенджер работает через веб хук, т.е. Вы предлагаете после получения команды и ее обработки, записывать в БД для этого юзера последнюю обработанную команду? 
Вроде бы не плохой вариант, но я вот думаю - а что скажет сервер если таких запросов будет много? (ну я конечно не рассчитываю на 10000+, но вполне вероятно что такое может быть). С кэшом не работал, попробую, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то в этом духе. Да тут больше подойдёт какое-то key=>value хранилище. Может быть Redis, или Memcache, ну или MongoDB на худой конец. Хотя изначально просто напишите абстрактный слой для работы с хранилищем и работайте с обычной базой. Если выстрелит бот, тогда купите себе VDS или дедик сервер, подключите что-то более производительное)))

```
class MessageSender {

    private $prevCommand;

    public function replyListener($command) {
        $this->prevCommand = $command;
    }

    public function postbackListener($command) {
        $this->prevCommand = $command;
    }
}

class FBMessenger {

    private $response;

    /**
     * @var MessageSender[] $senders
     */
    private $senders;

    private $bot;

    public function __construct($bot) {
        $this->bot = $bot;
        $this->getMessages();
        $this->processMessages();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        foreach ($this->senders as $senderID => $sender) {
            $objectData = serialize($sender);

            //Сохраняем в хранилище отправителей
            DB::connect()
                ->replace('sender')
                ->values([
                    'object_data' => $objectData
                ])
                ->where([
                    'sender_id' => $senderID
                ])
                ->execute();
        }
    }

    public function restoreSession($senderID) {
        //Достаём из хранилищя по оптравителю предыдущую сессию
        $objectData = DB::connect()
            ->select('object_data')
            ->from('sender')
            ->where([
                'sender_id' => $senderID
            ])
            ->execute()
            ->fetch();

        return unserialize($objectData);
    }

    public function getMessages() {
        $this->response = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
    }

    public function processMessages() {
        foreach ($this->response['entry'][0]['messaging'] as $message) {
            if (!empty($message['delivery'])) {
                continue;
            }

            $senderID = $message['sender']['id'];

            if (!isset($this->senders[$senderID])) {
                $this->senders[$senderID] = $this->restoreSession($senderID);
            }

            if (!empty($message['message'])) {
                $command = $message['message']['text'];
                $this->senders[$senderID]->replyListener($command);
            } else if (!empty($message['postback'])) {
                $command = $message['postback']['payload'];
                $this->senders[$senderID]->postbackListener($command);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо!